# Compare single website / browsing sessions at different points in time

Tags: browser, proxy

I need to compare single websites at different points in time. i.e. after a few days or after I have logged in. I'm not so much interested about the response times but more about the actual content, like js , images ... . Like is the js I get delivered today the same as yesterday. Is there a neat way to more or less automatically dump those and compare them (based on file hash)?

The best I could come up with is either using a proxy with TLS inspection which should deliver all downloaded files in clear text. Or use har files which should also include all the files the website is composed of. Is there something I those approaches could miss? Or are there maybe alternative ways of doing that?

Edit:

I need to download stuff after I have logged in and in particular I need to know what some scripts send/receive in the background. So I need to kind of record an active session and capture all data which goes over the wire in clear text.

Comment: If you are at the client side, you don't need to inspect TLS – you can terminate it. Couldn't you just `wget` the website? It'll download all the assets along with it.

Comment: Would be enough when in case of a static website. But I need to download stuff after I have logged in and in particular I need to know what some scripts send/receive in the background. So I need to kind of record an active session and capture all data which goes over the wire in clear text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to log in and perform some actions, then static downloads using `wget` or similar tools will not be enough. In this case, I suggest using [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/) to script the required actions, and dump all website content along with the response.

The basic idea would be to write a script in your preferred language (e.g. Python, Javascript, Ruby, ...) that uses the Selenium web driver to steer a browser. The script performs the login actions, clicks on elements, etc., and once you receive a response, you can store the body of the transferred page. A simple example for Python is [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28594142/435093), and some code that shows logging in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901304/435093).

You'd have to extend the code by iterating through all the external `<script>` tags, downloading their source, or, by going through all `<img>` tags, you could download the images. This way you can easily diff the main HTML code, and look at the individual filenames of called scripts/images.

Another possibility would be to run the Selenium script with [BrowserMob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy), which can export HAR files. This way you can combine the automation with dumping everything automatically. Of course, then you have to compare the HAR files, for which different viewers exist. Note that you'll have to use Man-in-the-Middle certificates with BrowserMob if you want it to work with HTTPS sites.

Comment: Are you aware of any solutions which can compare the har files or traffic dumps through a proxy? Say I go to superuser.com as prowin1 and get delivered superuser.js , then I login as prowin2 and get superuser.js but with a different content or instead evil.js. You could certainly diff the files and do some scripting. But maybe there is already a solution I'm unaware of.

Comment: None that I am aware of. Simply diffing the files would be the simplest way. Although of course I wouldn't expect such diffs to be very meaningful if the JS is minified/obfuscated, other than indicating that "something has changed".

Comment: Sure you would need to take a closer look when something has changed. But at least you know what to take a closer look at.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to download an entire website, see the article
[Best Free Website Ripper](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-web-site-ripper.htm).

This article contains reviews of several good rippers : HTTrack, PageNest, wget
and more.
I have used HTTrack in the past and it worked for me.

For going further back in time, you could try the
[Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/)
that tries to archive the entire Web. It takes regularly snapshots of the
websites, so you will find multiple versions to compare.

For capturing traffic, you will need a web-traffic monitor.
I can recommend two excellent products:
[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)
and Microsoft's
[Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: This would be enough for a static website. See other comment and edit of my question.

Comment: I added traffic capture products.

Comment: Thanks, are you aware of any differences for proxys like fiddler and har files. I don't mind about the website response times and stuff but more about captured data. i.e. could one solution miss some things?

Comment: I think har files are more oriented to performance. For debugging web proxy I have sometimes used [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).